# Stack Overflow for non-professionals

Tags: support

On About Stack Overflow, it is described to be a

> Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers

Well, I'm not a professional programmer so where do I go? My questions usually get downvoted there and since I'm a beginner, I don't understand the users. :/

Comment: Aren't you an enthusiast? You probably need to read a book on a topic before asking any questions about it, and maybe learn how to use search tools to find whether your questions already exist. That's likely all you're really missing.

Comment: Reading a book before asking a question might be overkill but certainly I would advise spending some time getting a feel for what type of questions attract downvotes instead of being well received.  Remember that Stack Exchange sites are not personal tutors.  Instead you are expected to try and answer your own question prior to posting, and then I would advise posting carefully until you understand what the community is expecting as minimum effort in question asking.

Comment: Reading a book or two while you get started is a reasonable requirement.  If you're farting around randomly and start asking questions because you lack the most basic knowledge, you're just wasting everybody's time.  I'm looking right now at two javascript books I bought because I was starting to do some frontend website work and... I was just farting around randomly, screwing up because I lacked some basic knowledge of certain things in javascript (DAMN YOU, CONTEXT!).  I've been in the game over 10 years.  Please, read a book or two.